# How to search for a hotel for family with more than 2 children?

Tags: uk, bookings, hotels, family

We are a family of 2 adults and 3 children aged between 8 and 10 in the UK. We do like to travel and usually end up booking our stay via AirBnB. Sometimes though we want to stay at a proper hotel or, better still, a real old-style B&B (there seems to be few of those left).

I am unable to find a hotel room(s) for a family of 5.  There are loads of hotels that advertise themselves as "family friendly" - but when checking, they can't accommodate a family of more than 4 people. Even larger hotels that offer joined rooms would only offer for family of 4 (i.e. two rooms, two people in each). This is especially problematic when looking outside of touristy areas. (I've been checking online as well as actually calling various hotels on the phone).

How can I search for a hotel or a real B&B that can accommodate our family of 5? I'm particularly interested in UK at this point, but more general worldwide answers are welcome.

Comment: Not sure why you can't book two different rooms to accomodate a family of 5.

Comment: @alamar I can - but with certain conditions.  I can't have children under 12 in a separate room on the other end of the corridor in a hotel.  And, as I wrote, with joined up room, I only have options for 2+2, not 2+3.

Comment: @alamar 1. in many cases you don't want to put your children to a separate room 2. two rooms are always more expensive than one (bigger) room

Comment: You can put a subset of children with one parent and another subset with a different parent. I'm not sure hotels actually have these huge rooms. Maybe check out hostels, these may be able to provide multi-bed rooms which you will then be able to book in full.

Comment: @alamar some hotels do have family suites.  We've stayed in some of these.  This would usually be a two-room suite with a sofa-bed.  So I know they do exist - it's just a question of how to search for them.

Comment: @alamar That solution is good enough from a safety point of view, but to have a nice holiday, the parents typically want to sleep together in one bed. So again, that's not an adequate solution for a family vacation (except maybe for a stopover accomodation).

Comment: Where exactly are you looking for accomodation? Searching for rooms with 5 beds on booking.com in my German home town gives me plenty of results, both cheap hostels, private apartments and all the way up to top notch 3000€/night suites with multiple bedrooms.

Answer (score 3):

You can find below a screenshot from booking.com app, you can customize the amount of people and rooms you are looking for. Sometimes your research will suggest two or more rooms instead of one, but that's because a single room is not available or is more expensive.
I imagine there are other search engines out there that could have similar results.
I use to love booking.com in the past, but their service has been really awful in the last 3 to 5 years. I'm still looking for a better alternative.
[image: booking.com app]

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried using booking.com - to no avail.  At best, it would offer family "rooms" for 2 adults plus 2 children; often it would list hotels as available but unable to book and offer to call the hotels - which would confirm that they cannot accommodate 5 people. And three quarters of matches it offers are airbnb style apartments.

Comment: It sounds like they are just not available in the region you are looking for. And I totally agree with you, booking has too many airbnbs now!

Comment: I use the same when searching for accomodation for my family of 6. Yes it's a pain, it's chaotic, and most of the results are not typical hotels. Most hotels are simply not built for such clientele, since there are not so many families with 3+ children these days. I usually settle with hostels or private accomodation.